# Pressure or confusion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, solid-state-physics, pressure

We all know that pressure is force per unit area.
for example we have a pressure of $5N/m^2$, so is the load of $5 N$ acts on the entire area or it acts just at a point i.e. is the load a point load or a uniformly distributed load.

Comment: you multiply with the area you are interested to see how much force falls on it, and you get the force on that area.

Comment: Entire area, otherwise the area would not be part of the definition.

Answer (score 1):

If the pressure is uniform, there is no problem, because you just multiply the pressure by the total surface area of interest.  However, if the pressure is varying on the surface, pressure should be regarded as a point function of location, and the contribution to the total force on the surface at a differential element of area on the surface dA is equal to pdA, where p is the local pressure at dA.  So the total force on the surface is $\int PdA$.  But, from another perspective, if the pressure is constant on a surface, it can still be regarded as a point function having a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 0):

It means 5 newtons acts on one meter square. Not exactly a point, any patch of any shape having 1 meter square area will have 5 newtons. If area is more then the force would be more if area is less force less.

F=PxA

Answer (score 0):

Pressure is force per unit area. If you have 5N/m^2, it means that a force of 5N acts at every 1 m^2 area of the surface. Suppose you have a 100m^2 area. Then the total force distributed over the entire surface is 500N which corresponds to about 50Kg.